# switch to root account and execute cd /root

Tags: shell, unix

below is code preview

```
function f1{  
 sudo su -      
 cd /root  
 yum install expect -y   
 wget <some url>
}

ssh  ec2-user@<ip> -i <key> "$(typeset -f f1); f1"
```

when I am running this script. It is hanging. I think it is not switching to root and executing rest of lines.

Can somebody help me to make it work.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70859/why-doesnt-sudo-su-in-a-shell-script-run-the-rest-of-the-script-as-root

Comment: how can this function be propagated to whatever machine you are targeting? it won't work in so many ways.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr By `$(typeset -f f1)`, I assume.